# Where does Internet Explorer 11 stored passwords?

Tags: internet-explorer

Where do Internet Explorer 11 stored passwords? I'm writing a script to clear saved password on IE. And I need to know where it saved passwords. Please help me

Comment: I believe these are stored in a Windows Vault in W10 and can't be easily accessed

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 saved passwords are stored in [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0#:%7E:text=Windows%2010,select%20Credential%20Manager%20Control%20panel.). It is known as **Windows Vault** in Windows 7 OS.

You can access Credential Manager by going to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`.

I try to search but did not get any script example to delete the saved IE 11 passwords from Credential Manager.

Comment: How about the file path or directory path that stored saved passwords?

Comment: As I informed you, IE Saved passwords do not get stored under any specific path or directory. It is stored in the Credential Manager. So you cannot access it from any path or folder.